# Using MAAS on Ubuntu 15.04 (Vivid Vervet)

Tags: maas, iscsi

i have just downloaded Ubuntu 15.04 Server AMD64 (Vivid Vervet) ISO and wanted to setup MAAS.  I went through a simple OS install and then added MAAS with the command

```
sudo apt-get install maas maas-dhcp maas-dns
```

Then i configured networking and imported the boot images and everything seemed to work correctly.

When trying to commission the first node the PXE boot process starts correctly but I eventually get a an error:

```
iscsistart: Logging into iqn.2004-05.com.ubuntu:maas:
ephemeral-ubuntu-amd64-generic-trusty-release 192.168.60.2:3260,1
iscsistart: can not connect to iSCSI daemon (111)!
```

Checking the running services with `netstat -an | grep 3260`, I can see that `iSCSI` isn't running.  What's the procedure for setting up `iSCSI` with MAAS?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and was able to get it working by disabling open-iscsi and enabling tgt:

```
systemctl stop open-iscsi
systemctl disable open-iscsi
systemctl enable tgt
systemctl start tgt
ps -ef | grep tgtd
grep tgtd /var/log/syslog
```

You should see the MaaS iSCSI targets in the log.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to keep in mind is that this can be caused by problems with the actual image being deployed; we have seen regressions like this in the daily cloud-images which we make available for testing ([for instance, in bug 1391354](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1391354)).